# Why is my Polygon on Google Maps Android API not Appearing?

Tags: android, google-maps

I do this in my java class:

```
//this is in On Create
    GameMapFragment map = new GameMapFragment();
    onMapReady(map.googleMap);
...
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                new LatLng(-18.142, 178.431), 2));

        // Polylines are useful for marking paths and routes on the map.
        map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().geodesic(true)
                .add(new LatLng(-33.866, 151.195))  // Sydney
                .add(new LatLng(-18.142, 178.431))  // Fiji
                .add(new LatLng(21.291, -157.821))  // Hawaii
                .add(new LatLng(37.423, -122.091))  // Mountain View
        );
    }
```

Yet all that shows up is my map without any points - not even a PolyLine. How do I make the polygon visible?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you should be calling [`map.getMapAsync(this);`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment.html#getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback)) instead of `onMapReady(map.googleMap);` in `onCreate` (assuming your `Activity` implements [`OnMapReadyCallback`](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/OnMapReadyCallback.html)).

Comment: I don't have that method